# Req.params shows data but req.params.variable_name shows up undefined

Tags: node.js

I am using a router function, inside a router class, in which I have defined a get request.

```
router() {
    let router = this.Router();
    router.get('/account/:account_name', this.getAccountDetails.bind(this));
    return router;
        }
```

Then I have defined the getAccountDetails function

```
  getAccountDetails(req, res){
          const eos_account_name = req.params.account_name;
          console.log(req.params);
          console.log(req.params.account_name);
          console.log("router debugger...", account_name);
          return this.service.getAccountDetails (account_name, res);
  }
```

My problem is, req.params returns { account_name: "accname" } but req.params.account_name comes up undefined. What is the issue here?

Comment: Try console.logging the following: `typeof req.params`, `Object.keys(req.params)`, `req.params[Object.keys(req.params)[0]]` and see what gets printed out to the console